# Image partly off screen killing as3 frame rate on IOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

I'm developing a game in as3 for iPhone, and I've gotten it running reasonably well (consistanty 24fps on iPhone 3G), but I've noticed that when the "character" goes partly off the screen, the frame rate drops to 10-12fps.  Does anyone know why this is and what I can do to remedy it?

Update - Been through the code pretty thoroughly, even made a new project just to test animations.  Started a image offscreen and moved it across the screen and back off.  Any time the image is offscreen, even partially, the frame rates are terrible.  Once the image is fully on the screen, things pick back up to a solid 24fps.  I'm using cacheAsBitmap, I've tried masking the stage, I've tried placing the image in a movieclip and using scrollRect.  I would keep objects from going off the screen, except that the nature of the game I'm working on has objects dropping from the top down (yes, I'm using object pooling.  No, I'm not scaling anything.  Striclt x,y translations).  And yes, I realize that Obj-C is probably the best answer, but I'd really like to avoid that if I can.  AS3 is so much nicer to write in

Comment: Odd behavior maybe something in your code is triggering a loop. Why not just keep it from going off the screen?

Comment: Agreed. It's probably your code

Comment: my guess is something about how cacheAsBitmap performs on iOS -- perhaps when your sprites are entirely on-screen, there's no offscreen buffer, but moving them partially offscreen doubles the amount of pixels the iDevice is managing per frame?  also not sure if there are any hints in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972967/cacheasbitmap-has-no-effect-on-a-sprite-masked-with-a-scrollrect-in-air-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

Try and take a look at the 'blitmasking' technique: http://www.greensock.com/blitmask

From Doyle himself:

> A BlitMask is basically a rectangular Sprite that acts as a high-performance mask for a DisplayObject by caching a bitmap version of it and blitting only the pixels that should be visible at any given time, although its bitmapMode can be turned off to restore interactivity in the DisplayObject whenever you want. When scrolling very large images or text blocks, BlitMask can greatly improve performance, especially on mobile devices that have weaker processorst