# cacheAsBitmap has no effect on a Sprite masked with a scrollRect in AIR for iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm developing a simple kinetic menu UI component for AIR for iPad. It's basically a lightweight fill-in for a combobox that matches the style of iOS. I have a sprite containing any where from 2 to 60 item buttons that pops up and lets you flick/ scroll through them, only showing about 7 items at any given time.

My first attempt at this used a mask over my sprite, moving my menu sprite up and down under the stationary mask. This produced lackluster results on the test device (< 20 fps).

I then tried a blitting solution, leaving the menu sprite off the display list and using BitmapData.draw() to render only the part to the list i needed visible. This produced the best results on my Windows dev platform, but this time the framerate dropped below 10 fps on iPad. I am assuming I was incurring either a taxing CPU usage or a GPU readback penalty. Originally I had hoped to be able to run my app a 60 fps, however I've ratcheted my goal down to a more humble 30 fps.

Which brings me to my 3rd attempt at this UI component using the sprite's .scrollRect masking function in conjunction with .cacheAsBitmap . Again, the observed behaviors differ wildly between AIR on Windows vs. iOS. On Windows it only redraws the part of the menu sprite bounded by the dimensions of the scrollRect as it should. With iOS i can touch the area of the screen above or below the visible area of the menu sprite and still drag the menu even though my finger is over "empty" space! The performance here is decent, hovering between (19 - 25 fps) and would almost certainly be perfect at 30 if it worked as it did on windows.

Does anyone have any ideas either about the scrollRect feature's behavior on AIR for iOS or a better way of implementing an iOS native style gliding menu in AIR for iOS?

Note, the above methods were tried in both CPU and GPU mode, but CPU mode performed vastly better. I used AIR 2.7 installed on top of Flash Pro CS 5.5, with FlashDevelop as my IDE.

Comment: One thing I've heard conflicting, or at least ambiguous, answers about is AIR for iOS's handling of bitmaps. I know that in GPU mode all BitmapData instances are cached on the GPU, but I've been unable to get a clear picture of how they are handled in CPU mode. My guess is the scrollRect/cacheAsBitmap anomaly is related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://esdot.ca/site/2011/fast-rendering-in-air-3-0-ios-android#comment-10

Really nice guy from the above link: "Ya, scrollRect is basically a no-go on mobile, basically forget that API even exists. Believe it or not… old school masking is the way to go. Round and round we go!"